# How do I increment a number using 0:00:00 format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, time

I am trying to create a time tracker in the following format; 0:00:00. The first zero represents the hour, then minutes, then seconds. Currently, I have a working function that increments the number every second. I know there is a proper way to do this with getDate() and then modifying the hours, minutes and seconds using getHours(), getMinutes() and so on. I just can't seem to get it all to work together. I've attached a working jsFiddle to show how far I've gotten.

The goal is to have it look something like ... 0:00:59 then turn into 0:01:00 and so on. Thank you.

Full example @ http://jsfiddle.net/London804/628xz9x7/2/

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
var start = setInterval(updateDisplay, 1000), // every millisecond call updateDisplay
   timer = $('#timer'),
   value = parseInt($(timer).find('.value').text(), 10);



function updateDisplay(){

    value++;
    $(timer).find('.value').text(value);
    if (value >= 60) {
        $('#sec').replaceWith("min");
    }
    if (value >= 3600) {
        $('#sec').replaceWith("hrs");
    }
    if (value >= 86400) {
        value = 0;
        console.log('stop and take a break, you have been working over 24hrs!');

    }
}

$('#stop').click(function(){
    clearInterval(start);
});
$('#reset').click(function(){
    clearInterval(start);
    value = parseInt($(timer).find('.value').text('0'));
});

});
```

Comment: Yes, that represents elapsed time.

Comment: one problem , if you replace a whole element, it doesn't exist next time you want to replace it. Just change it's inner text or html instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that doesn't involve all the slicing and dicing of html elements.  I'm using Date objects to track elapsed time in milliseconds and updating the display by extracting a substring of a standard format string provided by the Date object.

The end result will be more accurate as you are not relying on the timer to tick off seconds but are using an actual elapsed time between calls.

You still have to mess with the final output formatting but the Date object has nice functions that allow you to pull all the components you many need in terms our hours, minutes, seconds etc...

```js
var starting_ms ;
var elapsed ;
var $timer = $('#timer .value');
var $hrs = $('#elapsedtime #hrs');
var $min = $('#elapsedtime #min');
var $sec = $('#elapsedtime #sec');
var start;

function updateDisplay() {
  elapsed.setTime(Date.now() - starting_ms);
  $timer.text(elapsed.toUTCString().substr(20, 5));
  
  $hrs.text(elapsed.getUTCHours() );
  $min.text(elapsed.getUTCMinutes() );
  $sec.text(elapsed.getUTCSeconds() );
}

$('#submit').click(function() {
  if( start )
    clearInterval(start);
  starting_ms = Date.now();
  elapsed     = new Date(0);
  
  start = setInterval(updateDisplay, 1000); // every millisecond call updateDisplay
});

$('#stop').click(function() {
  clearInterval(start);
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
  clearInterval(start);
  starting_ms = Date.now();
  updateDisplay();
  
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent
}
body {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #A7A7A7), color-stop(0.51, #E4E4E4));
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'HelveticaNeue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%
}
.app {
  background: transparent url(../../img/logo.png) no-repeat center top;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 225px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 180px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: -115px 0px 0px -112px
}
.app #login {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase
}
.app #login:active {
  color: #cbcbcb
}
#welcome {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto
}
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1 / 1) and (min-width: 400px) {
  .app {
    background-position: left center;
    padding: 75px 0px 75px 170px;
    margin: -90px 0px 0px -198px
  }
}
h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center
}
.event {
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px 30px;
  padding: 2px 0px
}
.event.listening {
  background-color: #333333;
  display: block
}
.event.received {
  background-color: #4B946A;
  display: none
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 1.0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1.0
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 1.0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1.0
  }
}
.blink {
  animation: fade 3000ms infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade 3000ms infinite
}
#timer-container {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto
}
#timer-container #timer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #4887da;
  font-weight: bold
}
#timer-container label {
  display: block
}
#timer-container label input {
  width: 98%
}
#timer-container #button-container {
  text-align: center
}
#timer-container #button-container button {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 3px #9c899c;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 3px #9c899c;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 3px #9c899c;
  width: 35%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative
}
#timer-container #button-container button:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20%
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="welcome">
  <h2>Welcome please log in</h2>

  <p>Stuff ...</p>
</div>
<div>
  <fieldset id="timer-container">
    <div id="timer"><span class="value">0:00</span>  <span id="sec">sec</span>

    </div>
    <div id="button-container">
      <button id="submit" type="submit">Start</button>
      <button id='reset' type="reset">Reset</button>
      <button id="stop" type="stop">Stop</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  
  
  <table id="elapsedtime">
    <caption>Just for fun</caption>
    <tr>
      <td>Hrs</td><td>Min</td><td>Sec</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="hrs"></span></td><td><span id="min"></td><td><span id="sec"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start the timer, save the current date-time.

```
var start_dt = Date.now();
```

When you want to update the display, start by using the following:

```
var current_dt = Date.now();
var elapsed_ms = current_dt - start_dt;
```

That gives an accurate count of the elapsed time. Repeatedly incrementing a variable as you are doing will drift.

Now, it's time to format as H:MM:SS

```
function format_timer(ms) {
   var s = ("0" + Math.floor((ms / (      1000)) % 60)).substr(-2);
   var m = ("0" + Math.floor((ms / (   60*1000)) % 60)).substr(-2);
   var h =        Math.floor((ms / (60*60*1000))     );
   return h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}
```

Comment: Much more modular implementation than mine +1, this should be the answer.

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing this. When I put it inside my submit 'click' event it doesn't fire. Can you show me a working example please?

Comment: So how do I stop and pause the timer? Your solution is not working for me.

Comment: I don't know why your code doesn't work. If you have a question, you know how to ask it. Posting "It doesn't work" in the comments isn't it.

Comment: As for adding the ability to pause (or stop), you'd need to keep track of the timer's current state (active, paused, stopped), and how much time was left when it was paused.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it with converting your seconds to `dateTime` format and then with simple regex:

```
var myDate = new Date(null, null, null, null, null, value).toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1");
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/628xz9x7/6/

Comment: It works but it doesn't keep time properly. I knew using the getDate() method was the right approach I just didn't know how.

Comment: @London804 what do you mean by it does not keep time properly? Can you describe it more please?

Answer (score 0):

if you are certain on implementing this logic by yourself, you can make some use of some basic mathematics.

```
function updateDisplay(){

    value++;

    // Example for minutes
    if (value >= 60) {
        secs = value % 60;
        mins = (value - secs) / 60;
        $(timer).find('.value').text("00:"+min+":"+secs);
        //$('#sec').replaceWith("hrs");
    }
}
```

You can add the implementation for the other fields, but what we simply do here is find how many seconds are over the minute, by using modulus and then subtract the seconds from the minutes and divide by 60 to get the amount of minutes elapsed, we can then set the labels with these new values.

One thing you may want to do is provide a `formatNumber` method:

```
function formatNumber(number) {
   if (number < 10) {
      return "0" + number;
   }
   return number;
}
```

What this will do is provide the formatted string for the number to update label for values under 10, a test fiddle is here, I have not implemented all functionality but its a start for you : https://jsfiddle.net/628xz9x7/14/

Answer (score 0):

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Note that I do an iteration every millisecond instead of a second, for faster testing.

```
var start, value, timer = $('#timer');

$('#submit').click(function(){
   value = readTime(timer.text());
   start = setInterval(updateDisplay, 1); // replace 1 with 1000
});

$('#stop').click(function(){ clearInterval(start); });

$('#reset').click(function(){
    clearInterval(start);
    value = parseInt(timer.text(formatTime(0)));
});

function updateDisplay(){
    value++;
    timer.text(formatTime(value));
    if (value >= 86400) {
        value = 0;
        console.log('stop and take a break, you have been working over 24hrs!');
    }
}

function formatTime(t){
    var h = ('0' + parseInt( t / 3600 ) % 24).slice(-2),
        m = ('0' + parseInt( t / 60 ) % 60).slice(-2),
        s = ('0' + t % 60).slice(-2);
    return h+':'+m+':'+s;
}

function readTime(s){
    var r = s.split(':');
    return parseInt(r[0])*3600 + parseInt(r[1])*60 + parseInt(r[2]);
}
```